# Jet 4.0 in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7

I'm using windows 7 64 bit and I need to install Jet 4 provider in my odbc.

After some searching I found that it is possible that there is no way to have MS Jet 4 on windows 64 bit

is this true?

What can I do, considering this limitation, to run an MS Jet- based website on my 64 bit windows7?

Answer (score 1):

You can install 32bit providers in 64bit Windows, but only 32bit applications can use them. And vice versa, 64bit applications can only use the 64bit providers.

You should be able to use that particular provider as long as whatever application that needs it is also 32bit.

You can see what 64bit providers you already have by going to Control Pane->Administrative Tools->Data Sources (ODBC).

To see what 32bit providers you have installed, run C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.